# Zend Framework: Select query

Tags: mysql, select, zend-framework

I'm newbie on **Zend Framework**, I created DbTable , my primary key is **id** , and my table name is **user**:

```
<?php

class Application_Model_DbTable_User extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected $_name = 'user';
    protected $_primary = 'id';

}
```

after that ,I reviewed **Abstract.php**(Db/Table/Abstract.php) and I found out that I had to use *insert(array $data)*, so I created a model: (**Register.php**)

```
<?php

class Application_Model_Register
{
    public function CreateUser($array)
    {
        $dbTableUser = new Application_Model_DbTable_User();
        $dbTableUser -> insert($array);
    }

}
```

and finally , in my Controllers , I created **IndexController.php**

```
<?php
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $register = new Application_Model_Register();
        $register-> CreateUser(array(
               'username'=>'test'));
    }
}
```

It works correctly , but I have no idea about Select, How I select query from user table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

our controller should have to be like below

```
<?php
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function getdataAction()
    {
         $register = new Application_Model_Dbtable_Register();
         $register->getListOfUser(); 
    }
}
```

Now your model should have to be like this,

```
<?php

class Application_Model_DbTable_Register extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected $_name = 'user';
    protected $_primary = 'id';


    public function getListOfUser()
    {
         $db = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();
        $select  = $db->select()
                      ->from($_name,array('*'))
                      ->where(1);
        $data = $db->query($select)->fetchAll();
        return $data;         
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , and how to show result? 
maybe , I must create new Views, yes?

Comment: Yes to display results you need to create views.

Comment: I would do this `return $this->fetchAll($this->select()->where("something = ?, $something));`. This will return `Zend_Db_Table_Rowset` containing `Zend_Db_Table_Row` which can be extended (for example to create user class so quest returns user objects)